# Influx of Spam edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Has anyone else noticed an influx in SPAMMY edit suggestions? I've just declined 2, one of which took me a while to realize it was indeed spam. Both came from anonymous users.

Obviously we need to stay on top of our edits, but is there anything we can do to limit this, say for instance not allow anonymous users to edit?

## Update

Here are the edits I was referring to:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8341
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8334

... and another one: 
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8453

Comment: What were the edits and how did you find them to be spam?

Comment: Goodlord! I get your point..

Comment: On the positive side, these'll put you on a good track for a reviewer badge :P

Comment: @Brendan - nothing wrong with that.

Comment: They seem to all be done by some user names ckpepper... hmmmm.... :)

Comment: @Scott - you've foiled my plans!

Comment: Ck... you're not that stealthy.... we ALL see it !!! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been discussed, and usually denied almost immediately. I personally am in favor of limiting anonymous edits where, say, most than 50% of the text has changed.

Answer (score 2):

We have a complicated and sneaky system in place for dealing with spam edits. Keeping things vague for security reasons... the system basically figures out which edits are likely to be spam and blocks them. It learns from spam flags, so when there are spam edits, users should reject them **specifically as spam**.

[image]

If the problem persists after a while, follow the protocol Tim outlines [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228790/165581).

Comment: Also, I discovered a little design bug in the process of writing this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting post about this on SE's meta:

[Can we do more to warn anonymous users away from invalid edit suggestions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174409/can-we-do-more-to-warn-anonymous-users-away-from-invalid-edit-suggestions)

Unfortunately the question has no answers, but you could add your comment there to get more attention (especially if you have suggestions!).

Alternatively, adding the feature-request tag here will notify the SE overlords :)

Comment: careful what you ask for -- they may just slap another giant ugly and unreadable black bar on it and call it a day.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that when declining an edit you have the option to mark the rejection reason as spam. If the user who suggested the edit gets a certain amount of edits marked spam there is a consequence. Like first one, warning, second one loss of rep, final one loss of privilege to edit. (This of course could be several more than three/several less). Whatever the overlords deem best :)

Comment: I think the system is something like this. We can mark it as spam and I think negative votes/closing/flagging all act against someone and restrict some of their options. *I think I read something like this around here somewhere.. but I could just be imagining it*. :)