# Text box on the "reject suggested edit" dialog is misaligned

Tags: bug, design

Here's a screenshot from the reject dialog on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits:

[image]

(Ignore the orange annotation - I'm using a screenshot I made for [another post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/987/1976).)

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me, though. Screenshot from w7/FF. No problems zooming, either.

[image]

Comment: I imagine it's been fixed with the recent design tweaks. (Can't check right now - on mobile.)

Comment: @abbyhairboat That's what JohnB suspected as well. Might be an OS- or browser-specific issue, though.